# Quick explaination needed for row locking in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, jdbc, locking, rowlocking

I have a client-server application with 2 clients:

I need to make the reading of the database efficient when more than 1 client is reading it, without all clients getting the same rows. I use InnoDB engine for the tables, I do the queries like `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` and I don't use `SHARED MODE`

I need an explanation on how the process behaves in the following scenarios:

1. I have 30 rows in the table. Each client has one connection object to the database
2. Client A gets 15 rows with `SELECT ...FOR UPDATE`. Those rows are suppose to be locked.
3. Client B has to get the other 15 rows that are not locked by Client A, with `SELECT ..FOR UPDATE` respectively.

When I test this scenario I got Client B getting also the 15 rows of Client A. Why is that happening? I set `setAutoCommit(false)` and never do `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` query, therefore the connection never commits and locks that (e.g Client A did) have been set, are never released.

Can someone point me in right direction? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused, are you trying to lock the 15 rows or not?  If you are, you are missing:

```
START TRANSACTION
```

Here is the link to the transaction docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: As he is using JDBC, he should set use `setAutoCommit(false)` on his connection instead. The JDBC driver is responsible for transaction management as internally there are dependencies on transaction state as well, and issuing `START TRANSACTION` like that could bring the driver in an inconsistent state.